# Android HorizontalScrollView Repeated Auto-Scroll in a Loop

Tags: android, android-layout, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

I need to make a [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) scroll automatically.

By automatically, I mean it should:

1. Smooth scroll automatically from Left to Right
2. Once the Right edge is reached, smooth scroll backwards i.e. Right to Left.
3. Repeat 1 & 2 infinitely.

I've tried the following implementation, which doesn't seem to fully work.
(The view scrolls from L to R, but fails to scroll from R to L)

```
Timer timer = new Timer("horizontalScrollViewTimer");
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (horizontalScrollView.canScrollHorizontally(View.FOCUS_RIGHT)) {
                    horizontalScrollView.smoothScrollBy(5, 0);
                } else {
                    while (horizontalScrollView.canScrollHorizontally(View.FOCUS_LEFT)) {
                        horizontalScrollView.smoothScrollBy(-5, 0);
                        if (!horizontalScrollView.canScrollHorizontally(View.FOCUS_LEFT)) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

             }
        });
    }
}, 3000, 50);
```

Any help will be appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

modify and try this....

```
private boolean scrollingLeft = false;

....

Timer timer = new Timer("horizontalScrollViewTimer");
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (scrollingLeft) {
                        if (horizontalScrollView.getScrollX() == 0) {
                            horizontalScrollView.smoothScrollBy(5, 0);
                            scrollingLeft = false;
                        } else {
                            horizontalScrollView.smoothScrollBy(-5, 0);
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (horizontalScrollView.canScrollHorizontally(View.FOCUS_RIGHT)) {
                            horizontalScrollView.smoothScrollBy(5, 0);
                        } else {
                            horizontalScrollView.smoothScrollBy(-5, 0);
                            scrollingLeft = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }, 3000, 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

The @soumyadip001 answer did not work for me because the scrollingLeft was never true but this solution of mine worked for me. With this solution you can achieve infinite loop.

```
  int scrollAmount =0; //compute scrolling amount
  boolean scrollingLeft = false;

   //get the view at the rightmost part of the horizontalscrollview
   View viewRight = horizontalScrollView.getChildAt(horizontalScrollView.getChildCount() - 1);

  Timer timer = new Timer("horizontalScrollViewTimer");
  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if (!scrollingLeft) {
                        horizontalScrollView.smoothScrollBy(5, 0);
                        scrollAmount+= 5; //increment scroll amount
                        if (scrollAmount >= viewRight.getRight()) { //check 
                            scrollingLeft = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if (scrollingLeft ) {
                            horizontalScrollView.smoothScrollBy(-5, 0);
                            scrollAmount-=5;
                            if(scrollAmount<=0) {
                                scrollingLeft = false;
                                scrollAmount =0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }, 3000, 50);
```

Note: cancel the timer onPause to avoid memory leak or crash

```
 onPause(){
   if(timer!=null)
     timer.cancel();

 }
```